# ios Unregistering an Observer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was reading Apple Documents and saw that:

> Before an object that is observing notifications is deallocated, it
>   must tell the notification center to stop sending it notifications.
>   Otherwise, the next notification gets sent to a nonexistent object and
>   the program crashes.

I tried to crash app to learn better how it is actually working.

However, even if I did not put this code inside SecondViewController dealloc, it still does not crash after sending notification. I'am obviously adding observer and going back from secondViewController and pushing notification in viewController. So, Why do we need remove observer if this program does not crash?

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

Rest code is:

//ViewController:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:NO completion:^{}];
    [secondViewController release], secondViewController = nil; }

- (IBAction)push:(id)sender {
    // All instances of TestClass will be notified
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:self]; }
```

//SecondViewController:

```
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc]; }

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                                     name:@"TestNotification"
                                                   object:nil];

    }
    return self; }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     }

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
    // [notification name] should always be @"TestNotification"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.
    NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!"); }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}]; }
```

Comment: Remove observer like this - 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:@"TestNotification"]; and notify like this -             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:nil userInfo:nil];

Comment: Are you sure SecondViewController was deallocated before the notification fired?

Comment: As to crashing if you fail to remove the observer, there is no *guarantee* that your app will crash while you're testing it.  But it's almost certain to crash when someone is using it, and very likely when Apple is running your app through certification.

Comment: Update: "If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, and you used addObserver(_:selector:name:object:), you do not need to unregister the observer. If you forget or are unable to remove the observer, the system cleans up the next time it would have posted to it." I put a link to the Apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Reno Jones is right.
Remove observer like this - `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"TestNotification" object:nil];`

One more thing to add to his answer is you should remove the observer in the `- (void)dealloc {}` method - this is the method that is called when self is deallocated.

EDIT:

I've looked at the code and I have seen you are not using arc. one more question why are you not using ARC in your application? Do you have a good reason to stress yourself with reference counting , i do not see the point?

Second could you move the addObserver in the viewDidLoad method and see it that crashes your app.

Comment: That needs to be `removeObserver:self` or `removeObserver:self name:@"TestNotification" object:nil`

Comment: @Kevin is correct removing observer @"TestNotification" is removing the static string object from the observation list... that isn't I presume what you want.

Comment: Hope this issue is sorted out?

Comment: You did not read the question. I want to crash the app for better understanding things. But, it's not crashing even if I remove removeObserver:self.

Comment: if you didn't manage to crash the app did you try moving the add observer in the viewdidappera or viewdidload and not removing the observer?

Answer (score 0):

Either `dealloc` method of `SecondViewController` is not being called because the object is still in the memory, or `push:(id)sender` method is not called after the controller is deallocated. Otherwise, It would definitely crash. Make sure that the methods are called by putting breakpoints.